# Create user through procedure on another database via database link

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, database-link

I'd like to create users through procedure on another database via database link.I am getting error while executing procedure.
Here are the code which i used.

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE hostname   
(host_name in varchar2,user_name in VARCHAR2, pass_word in VARCHAR2,    
table_space in varchar2,pro_file in varchar2)    
as    
db_link_name varchar2(30);    
begin    
select db_link into db_link_name from all_db_links where host=host_name;    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||db_link_name||('CREATE     USER '||user_name||' IDENTIFIED BY '||pass_word||'     
DEFAULT TABLESPACE '||table_space||' PROFILE '|| pro_file||' ACCOUNT UNLOCK');    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||db_link_name||    
('GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE,Create table,create session,create     view,create sequence,create procedure,create job,create synonym TO '||user_name);    
end;    
/    
execute hostname('orcl1','rahul1','rahul','users','default');
```

> Error:     ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement     ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.HOSTNAME", line 6     ORA-06512: at line 1
>   00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: I think you need to use an anonymous block to call a procedure.

Comment: Hello mustaccio its working with anonymous block i tryed but i need to wrire procedure for front end so front end can call it anytime

Comment: You really should not be creating objects in the SYS schema. You should create your own user/schema and only use that. You should only connect as SYS to do specific DBA tasks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have got a little confused by some of the advice provided by the commenter mustaccio.  What he meant to say is that the SQL strings in your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements need to use PL/SQL blocks in order to call stored procedures.

In other words, instead of writing

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement ... ';
```

you should write

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement ... ; END;';
```

For your procedure, I would recommend doing introducing a local variable for the strings you are passing to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  These can be notoriously tricky to get right, and if you've assigned them to a local variable you can easily output them using `dbms_output.put_line`.  In fact, I did exactly this while fixing up the problems in your procedure.  I would recommend continuing to do this if you wish to modify or extend your procedure.

Anyway, here's what I ended up with, which appeared to work:

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE hostname   
  (host_name in varchar2,user_name in VARCHAR2, pass_word in VARCHAR2,    
  table_space in varchar2,pro_file in varchar2)    
as    
  db_link_name      varchar2(30);
  l_ddl_sql         varchar2(4000);
begin    
  select db_link into db_link_name from all_db_links where host=host_name; 
  l_ddl_sql := 'begin dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||db_link_name||'(''CREATE     USER '||user_name||' IDENTIFIED BY '||pass_word||'     
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE '||table_space||' PROFILE '|| pro_file||' ACCOUNT UNLOCK''); END;';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_ddl_sql;

  l_ddl_sql := 'begin dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||db_link_name||    
    '(''GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE,Create table,create session,create     view,create sequence,create procedure,create job,create synonym TO '||user_name || '''); END;';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_ddl_sql;
end;
/
```